# How to see div (etc) rectangles in some browser

Tags: html, layout, browser, geometry, bounding-box

In order to better *program* and *develop* my *Javascript* and *HTML5* skills, I would like to visualize the actual bounding box of various HTML commodities. This also would help in *debugging* and the eventual development of *best practices*.

Android devices have a handy feature wherein via developer settings one can turn on and off the explicit drawing of bounding rectangles for various layouts and widgets.

Apart from hacking away at Firefox source, does SO know of how I might achieve a similar result for the web? Any browser really will be fine.

[image]

Comment: For FF and Chrome get the Web Developer toolbar. Then under the "outline" tab you have several different options.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed. It is not requesting any tool, it is requesting any solution, which it found.

Comment: It was closed quite a while ago, but I'm guessing because it is asking for a full blown solution (which I suppose might be interpreted as "asking for resource / tool etc"), rather than showing an attempted solution and indicating what is wrong (which to me is more "too broad", but semantics...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Firefox 24, you can do something similar per-page with Firebug.  In Firebug's CSS pane, right-click and select New Rule.  The rule is:

```
html * { border: 1px solid #00f !important }
```

"html *" selects all elements in the document, and "!important" overrides other stylesheet
settings.  You could apply this to all pages using a Greasemonkey script; example [here](http://greasemonkey.win-start.de/patterns/add-css.html)

**edit** This shows you the border and the padding for any particular element but doesn't show that element's margins in the CSS [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).  However, the outline on a parent element will include the margins of child elements.  For example, on the html

```
<html><body><div style="width: 200px">
  <p style="margin: 50px;">Lorem ipsum</p></div>
</body></html>
```

the Firebug technique shows (annotations in purple):

[image: screenshot of results]